# Make ends of hair mesh sharp

Tags: particles

I made a 3D model of a girl from a game I play and I have the hair all set up, but it's flat on the ends and I don't know how to fix that.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you using BI or Cycles?

Comment: bi .... thats the render :)

Answer (score 2):

## BI

Reduce the value of *Tip* to in the hair material under *Materials > Strand > Size*:

[image]

## Cycles

Again decrease the value of *Tip*, but in *Particle Settings > Cycles Hair Rendering*:

[image]

Comment: Hm , that doesn't seem to be working? do you have any other ideas?

Comment: @Knuckles209cp Are you using *Paths* or *Objects* as hair particles? Could you add some screenshots of your material and particle settings (or upload your .blend)?

Comment: I dont have particle settings , i am using a mesh for my hair . ill take some pictures of the settings for you

Comment: @Knuckles209cp Ohh.. you mean that they are all basically mesh planes?

Comment: Yes :) , i have the actual girl from the game if you want to look? https://www.google.co.nz/search?q=final+sarah&espv=210&es_sm=91&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=OsnqUoDiAYSGkQWg_oGIDA&ved=0CAkQ_AUoAQ&biw=1916&bih=898#q=final+fantasy+sarah&tbm=isch&facrc=_&imgdii=_&imgrc=mbkZpehO7waGVM%253A%3BZP6DbmJc6fhtNM%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.creativeuncut.com%252Fgallery-18%252Fart%252Fff13-2-serah-portrait.jpg%3Bhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.creativeuncut.com%252Fgallery-18%252Fff13-2-serah-portrait.html%3B1000%3B1100

Comment: Oh the question was ment to say MESH instead of particle , my fault sorry

Comment: @Knuckles209cp Could you use an alpha texture to make it look like they're sharp? Or do they really need to be sharp?

Comment: i could do the alpha texture ... is it possible to do it any other way though??

Comment: @Knuckles209cp Well, how easy it is depends on the topology of the hair, if the hair pieces are separate objects, have linked mesh data (and are deformed by a modifier), etc.

Comment: ALL the hair is just one mesh